# Do I always need a web server with spring integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-integration

I'm new to *spring-integration* and what I want to acheive is lanching a *spring-batch* job from an external web application.

Batchs are run in two diffrent maners. Cron (outside of the scope of this question) and started manually by a user action like shown in the picture below

[image]

Now each batch is configured like the following :

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Batch1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Batch1Application.class)
                .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
                .registerShutdownHook(true)
                .run(args);
    }
}
```

Currently when the web app receives an action it calls the same sh script used in by cron configuration :

```java
//...
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(List.of(/*path to batch-1-script.sh*/));
Process process = processBuilder.start();
//...
```

The script do something like : `java -jar batch1.jar`

It works fine and contexts of each application is not shared.

Now I want to move to *spring-integration*. I've found several articles/videos that talk about *spring-integration* and *spring-batch-intergartion*, But all use the same web-app to launch jobs using a simple `DirectChannel` (as context contains all the needed beans).

---

My question is how to keep each batch listening for messages to come and then start executing ?

Do I need to convert them all to web app and add *spring-integration* on them ?

Comment: No, you do not need a web server to use Spring Integration, and your application does not need to be a web app. You can have any kind of Java app that puts something on a Spring Integration channel to let it do what it needs to do. The putting something on a channel does not necessarily need to be done from a Spring MVC controller, for example.

Comment: if no server is needed, how my batch (jvm) listen to the incoming messages ? Currently each batch is running in a separate jvm (process) and shutdown just after it is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Integration is just a library and it fully is not tied to any container specifics. If you need to expose an interaction with your application via HTTP, only then you need to have this application on Web server.

It is not clear from your description what does that `batch-1-script.sh` do to start the batch application, but probably you can live this feature and just change its service implementation to emit a message to a channel instead of direct job execution call as it is right now.

On the other hand you can take any messaging broker in between and publish a message to the topic to let those apps to listener for such a message on their side.

See possible endpoints in Spring Integration for this solution: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/endpoint-summary.html#spring-integration-endpoints.

Also, since you say that you can some script at a the moment, it sounds like everything is done on the same host, so probably you can take an advantage from ZeroMQ as a protocol between Web APP and those workers: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/zeromq.html#zeromq

Comment: thank you for the answer, I can see more clearly now

Comment: It seems I have similar requirement. I have to deploy around 8 java batch job (docker container) in separate web app on one Azure app service plan(Premium V3). Java batch code need to be modify to include spring batch scheduler so that batch jobs can be schedule to run at different time through code itself and some will trigger based on new file arrival at storage location.  For trigger based do we need to convert batch code to Rest api. If yes then will rest api will be able to handle batch .csv processing million of records. IF possible could you please share your experience